# SaveChanges() doesn't work?

Tags: entity-framework, savechanges

I have the following code:

```
User user = new User();

user.Name = "ABC";
user.Age = "12";

_context.AddToUser(user);
_context.SaveChanges();

Meta meta = new Meta();

meta.UserID = user.ID;
meta.Info = "User Info";

_context.AddToMeta(meta);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

User.ID is Identity and is set to increase by 1 when a new record was inserted. When I run the above code. I got a new user ID  by using user.ID but there is no new record was added in User table.

If I comment the last _context.SaveChanges() then the new record is added. I'm new with EF, I've searched for a while but still don't know why.

Any helps would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

you forgot:

```
_context.AddToMeta(meta);
```

Comment: I missed that line, but there is no new record is added in User table, not Meta table.

Comment: maybe there's a foriegn key attribute on User that you should set